# Stop Excel from formatting list of zip codes ina cell

Tags: excel

I recognize this is a simple question, but it's stumped me.

I'm attempting to enter a comma-separated list of zip codes into one cell, so I can then use the Text of Columns feature to split the zip codes up by comma delimiter.

Unfortunately, no matter how I format the cell, the information pastes weird:

General - `6.04816040860416E+149` (General)
Number - `604816040860416000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00`

And I want to look like this:

`60481,60408,60416,60407,60935,60421,60410,60913,60474,60442,60969,60424,60436,60961,60444,60433,60914,60950,60450,60431,60915,60941,60432,60435,60434,60451,60917,60902,60447,60901`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try placing a single quote `'` at the beginning of the cell and then typing in your string of numbers. The single quote will ensure Excel recognizes the string of numbers as text.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the cell *before* you paste the list into excel and format the cell as Text.

Another option is to put a single quote `'` in the cell before pasting (don't click away from the cell between typing `'` and pasting! If you do, push <kbd>F2</kbd> then paste, or paste in the formula bar after the single quote), so that the text is treated as text. This won't affect the results of the Text to columns function.